# Swift 4 hidden buttons not reappearing

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, uipickerview, xcode9

This is a follow up to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49913442/swift-4-show-hide-button-based-on-picker-view-selection). I was able to get the buttons to hide just fine but they don't reappear when I select the college education option. Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var eduField: UITextField!   
var education = ["Middle School Education", "High School Education", "College Education"]   
var eduPicker = UIPickerView()

@IBOutlet weak var associate: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var bachelor: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var master: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    eduPicker.delegate = self
    eduPicker.dataSource = self
    eduField.inputView = eduPicker

    if eduField.text == "College Education"{
      associate.isHidden = false
      bachelor.isHidden = false
      master.isHidden = false
    }
    else{
      associate.isHidden = true
      bachelor.isHidden = true
      master.isHidden = true
  }
}
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return education.count
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    eduField.text = education[row]
    eduField.resignFirstResponder()
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return education[row]
    }
}
```

I know that my code is partially correct as these buttons hide or appear is I change the values in else from false to true but I guess I don't fully understand how the values are stored in the viewpicker as my code obviously doesn't recognize the values I tell it to. I feel really dumb asking about roughly the same issue twice in a twenty-four hour period but, this is driving me insane. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are not updating your buttons statuses.

I'd suggest having a method like:

```
func updateButtonsVisibility() {
    if eduField.text == "College Education"{
      associate.isHidden = false
      bachelor.isHidden = false
      master.isHidden = false
   } else {
       associate.isHidden = true
       bachelor.isHidden = true
       master.isHidden = true
   }
}
```

And then call that same method both in `viewDidLoad()` and at the end of `func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)`.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thank you!

Comment: Sure thing! Although this wasn't a part of your question, I'd recommend looking into `enum`s. The goal of using `enum` in your example is to turn your `education` array into an `enum`, which will help you prevent comparing strings like `if eduField.text == "College Education"`. This is not the best practice, as you could easily make a typo and get unexpected behaviour in your app, which is then more complex to debug. Please see https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/08/04/swift-enums-hard-coded-strings/ or https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/09/02/replace-magic-strings-with-enumerations-in-swift/